# removing .html from url and displaying the content of .html using .htaccess

Tags: html, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am trying to remove the .html from all my files...

this is my .htaccess file

---

```
Options -Indexes
Options -MultiViews
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on


###example.com/page will display the contents of example.com/page.html

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ $1.html [L,QSA]


###from example.com/page.html to example.com/page

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /.*\.html\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^(.*)\.html$ /$1 [R=301,L]
```

---

This works for pages in the main directory  (domain.com/page.html directs to domain.com/page ...and displays contents of domain.com/page.html)

However, it doesn't not work for pages in another directory like domain.com/Folder/Page.html

when user for to this page, it just redirects to the file structure

Please HELP!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code:

```
Options -Indexes
Options -MultiViews
Options +FollowSymlinks

RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(.+?)\.html[\s?] [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1 [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.html -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ /$1.html [L]
```

Comment: Thank you! the problem i figured out was that i had a folder in the domain.com/Folder/ called page, so when instead of loading page.html it loaded the files in the folder page

Comment: OK great to know that. Would you mind accepting the answer since answer is still correct.